# facebook SDK with react-native: no framework search path

Tags: ios, facebook, react-native, search-path

I was playing around with Facebook SDK with react-native generated ios app template. I was following the instructions here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/getting-started  but somehow did not see `Framework Search Paths` mentioned in **step 4.5**.  the react-native generated ios project seems to only have `header search path`, as shown below.

I was using latest Xcode version (9.3)
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try upgrading project templates - [Upgrade guide](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/upgrading.html#2-upgrade-your-project-templates)

Or try to use RN wrappers available on the internet.

I personally like these two - [this](https://github.com/facebook/react-native-fbsdk) and [this](https://github.com/magus/react-native-facebook-login)

Good luck!

Comment: thanks for the suggestions ! by any chance do you have any recommendation for linkedin-login as well ? This is the one that I am trying out https://github.com/jodybrewster/react-native-linkedin-login.

Comment: @jyhk use OAuth or passport.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change `Basic` to `All` tab at the top of the menu

[image]

No need of upgrading anything